# How can I use foreach and array instead of a text file

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I need help with "data.php" . How can I make the "data.php"  use foreach and an array instead of writing to text file ?
With this come it makes it so that the information is written down in a txt file
And I need it to be in an Array and to use Foreach .
Weed all of the information to go into an array and then by using Foreach to show it up .

**letters.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Домашна 3</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Tahoma;
            }
            
            table, td {
                margin: auto;
                padding: 7px;
                width: 50%;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                background: #00FFFF;
            }
            
            th {
                font-size: 40px;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            
            h1 {
                margin: auto;
                padding: 30px;
                background: #bfeaff;
            }
            
            input {
                margin: 10px;
            }
            
            p {
                font-size: 20px;
                margin: auto;
                padding: auto;
            }
            
            hr {
                margin: 15px;
                padding: auto;
            }
            
            input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-right: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<center>
<h1>СЪЗДАВАНЕ НА ПИСМО/A</h1>
<label for="firstName_Receiver">Име на получател:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstName_Receiver" name="firstName_Receiver" required /><br />
<label for="lastName_Receiver">Фамилия на получател:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastName_Receiver" name="lastName_Receiver" required /><br />
<hr />
<label for="firstName_Sender">Вашето име:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstName_Sender" name="firstName_Sender" required /><br />
<label for="lastName_Sender">Вашата фамилия:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastName_Sender" name="lastName_Sender" required /><br />
<hr />
<p>Съдържания:</p><br />
<textarea  name="firstContext" rows="6" cols="60" required></textarea><br /><br />
<textarea  name="secondContext" rows="6" cols="60" required></textarea><br /><br />
<p>Послепис:</p><br />
<textarea name="Afterword" rows="4" cols="40" required></textarea>
 <hr />
<input type="submit" value="Изпрати" name="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Изчисти" />
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
require "data.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
    if (!file_exists("letters.txt"))
    {
        $letters = fopen("letters.txt", "w+");
            fwrite($letters,
            "Уважаеми (а), " . $_POST["firstName_Receiver"] . " " . $_POST["lastName_Receiver"] . "<br />" . "\n" .
            $_POST["firstContext"] . "<br />" . "\n" .
            $_POST["secondContext"] . "<br />" . "\n" .
            $_POST["Afterword"] . ", " . $_POST["firstName_Sender"] . " " . $_POST["lastName_Sender"] . "!" . "\n" . "\n"
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $letters = fopen("letters.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($letters,
            "<hr />" . "Уважаеми (а), " . $_POST["firstName_Receiver"] . " " . $_POST["lastName_Receiver"] . "<br />" . "\n" .
            $_POST["firstContext"] . "<br />" . "\n" .
            $_POST["secondContext"] . "<br />" . "\n" .
            $_POST["Afterword"] . ", " . $_POST["firstName_Sender"] . " " . $_POST["lastName_Sender"] . "!" . "\n" . "\n"
        );
    }
    fclose($letters);
    echo file_get_contents("letters.txt");
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where is your data coming from (which variable or file) and where do you want it to go (another variable, file, etc.)?

Comment: I want the data from the form to be saved in an array inside data.php .I want to be able to submit the form however many times  I want , each time the data from the form to get added inside the array .In the end I need all of  the data to be displayed

Comment: You already write data in to a text file with this code `fwrite($letters);`

Comment: I got the code from a friend and need to change it the way I wrote

Comment: If you want to save the data every time and continue to add it to an array, you need to store it somewhere between submissions.

Comment: Yeah but I need to do it with an array and foreach that is the problem

Comment: Tavarish you have all data comming from form in the $_POST array. Loop through it. Add new array on the session and inclued the $_POST into it.

Comment: You can cleanly store the data as json in a .json file or store the arrays in a SESSION.  There are multiple ways to solve this question.  There could be 10 different answers posted to this question.  When reading your file, you could explode on the `<hr />`, but then what if the user data has a newline in it?  Your lines of data will be hard to correctly parse.  I recommend not mucking around with section delimiters.  Use a json file.

Comment: Mehrwaz why are you suggesting to store in session? what if session expires all data will be lost

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see any benefit in bloating your question body with css dexlarations.  Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use session and store the data into a new array. Currently I do not have PHP installed on my computer make sure the syntax is correct please.

Please do not forget that the session should be started at the top of the page.

```
<form method="post">
    <table style="text-align: center;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>СЪЗДАВАНЕ НА ПИСМО/A</h1>
                <label for="firstName_Receiver">Име на получател :</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName_Receiver" name="firstName_Receiver" /><br />
                <label for="lastName_Receiver">Фамилия на получател:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName_Receiver" name="lastName_Receiver" /><br />
                <hr />
                <label for="firstName_Sender">Вашето име:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName_Sender" name="firstName_Sender" /><br />
                <label for="lastName_Sender">Вашата фамилия:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName_Sender" name="lastName_Sender" /><br />
                <hr />
                <p>Съдържания:</p><br />
                <textarea name="firstContext" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea><br /><br />
                <textarea name="secondContext" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea><br /><br />
                <p>Послепис:</p><br />
                <textarea name="Afterword" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
                <hr />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="Изчисти" />
                <button type="submit" name='save'>Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
session_start();

if ( (isset($_POST["Submit"]) || isset($_POST['save'])) && !empty($_POST['firstName_Receiver']) ){
    $_SESSION['DaraArray'][] = $_POST;
}

if(isset($_POST['save']) && isset($_SESSION['DaraArray'])){
    //Do what you want and unset the $_SESSION['DataArray'];
    foreach($_SESSION['DaraArray'] as $Data){
        // Your code inside loop 
        echo '<pre';
        print_r($Data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    unset($_SESSION['DaraArray']);
}
?>
```